# Move window to max X in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I creating a port of a fnf mod to unity to create a remaster.

I having problems with this mechanic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-l49NvjGBY

I have to create a C# `MonoBehaviour` that move the window to the min and max X position of the screen.

How do I do this via c# in unity?

Comment: Are you doing this in the C# language, or the UnityScript language? You've tagged both.

Comment: What have you tried? Check [Screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html)

Comment: Unity no longer supports Unity Script (the JavaScript-like language) since ~Unity 2017.  See _[UnityScript’s long ride off into the sunset](https://blog.unity.com/community/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset);_ and  _[How to use JavaScript language in unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/165976/how-to-use-javascript-language-in-unity)_

Comment: I use c# in unity.